# How to install openjdk-18?

Tags: apt, openjdk, minecraft

I am trying to optimize Minecraft on Linux and it says to get the latest OpenJDK JRE.

My current setup is:

```bash
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java                                                                                                   
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
$ uname -m                                                                                                                                
x86_64
$ lsb_release -a                                                                                                                          
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$ lspci | grep VGA                                                                                                                        
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

When I try to install openjdk-18 JRE what I get is an error:

```bash
$ sudo apt install -y openjdk-18-jre                                                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-18-jre
```

And when I try to search apt-cache I only find:

```bash
apt-cache search openjdk                                                                                                                
default-jdk - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
default-jdk-doc - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (documentation)
default-jdk-headless - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (headless)
default-jre - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
default-jre-headless - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)
openjdk-11-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-11-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-11-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-11-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-11-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-11-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-11-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
crypto-policies - unify the crypto policies used by different applications and libraries
jtreg - Regression Test Harness for the OpenJDK platform
libhsdis0-fcml - HotSpot disassembler plugin using FCML
libjax-maven-plugin - Using the xjc goal with OpenJDK 11+
libreoffice - office productivity suite (metapackage)
openjdk-11-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-11-jre-dcevm - Alternative VM for OpenJDK 11 with enhanced class redefinition
openjdk-11-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
openjdk-8-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-8-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-8-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-8-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-8-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-8-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-8-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-8-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-8-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
uwsgi-app-integration-plugins - plugins for integration of uWSGI and application
uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-11 - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 11)
uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-11 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 11)
uwsgi-plugin-ring-openjdk-11 - Closure/Ring plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 11)
uwsgi-plugin-servlet-openjdk-11 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 11)
java-package - Utility for creating Java Debian packages
openjdk-13-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-13-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-13-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-13-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-13-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-13-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-13-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-13-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
openjdk-13-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
openjdk-16-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-16-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-16-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-16-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-16-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-16-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-16-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-16-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
openjdk-16-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
openjdk-17-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-17-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-17-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-17-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-17-jdk-headless - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
openjdk-17-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-17-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-17-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero
openjdk-17-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
postgresql-10-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 10
postgresql-11-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 11
postgresql-12-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 12
postgresql-13-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 13
postgresql-14-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 14
postgresql-9.5-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 9.5
postgresql-9.6-pljava - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 9.6
```

I'll probably just install openjdk-17-jre but now this really bugs me cause I can [see it here](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-18).

If anyone cares Minecraft Launcher says I am on Minecraft 1.19

Guides I'm following:

- [How To Install Java with Apt on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-22-04)
- [How to Install and Optimize Minecraft on Linux: 8 Key Steps](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-steps-install-optimize-minecraft-linux/)

Comment: It’s worth noting the Debian page you linked appears to be saying it is in the Unstable version of Debian. Not the stable version. That said, you can download it from Adoptium if you want to try it https://adoptium.net/

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to follow 22.04 tutorials when you are running a different release of Ubuntu (you are running 20.04) for precisely the reason you encountered -- version problems. My own Minecraft server works just fine on earlier releases of OpenJDK. If you really want the absolute newest-bleeding-edge, then release-upgrade your system to 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install it in /opt/ so it does not interfere with the currently installed version. Commands:

Download:

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18/43f95e8614114aeaa8e8a5fcf20a682d/36/GPL/openjdk-18_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Extract the download (replace {version} with the one downloaded):

```
tar -xvf openjdk-18._linux-{version}
```

Move it to /opt/:

```
sudo mv jdk-18* /opt/
```

(replace jdk-18 to something else if you want) and set the environment variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-18
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

To check if that went correctly:

```
cd /opt/jdk-18/
java --version
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

By re-doing the exports to exclude `/opt/jdk-18` you restore the old situation

Comment: Rinzwind, during the extract the download step it says {version}. Would that look like tar -xvf openjdk-18._linux-jdk18

Comment: It's not changing the environment variables. They still remain in java 11. Anyone know why?